# Project using Arduino microcontroller board

Tags: arduino

I want to start a project using arduino microcontroller board. In this project I will use a Mini Thermal Receipt Printer, barcode scanner and the arduino ethernet shield to transfer data to my pc and from my pc. my question is, what arduino board should I buy for such project? is the arduino uno is enough?

Comment: There is a full tutorial here: http://learn.adafruit.com/mini-thermal-receipt-printer/overview  - the UNO will be fine.

Comment: If you use Raspberry pai instead of arduino it will be more affordable.. See the difference between arduino and raspberry pai Visit ->> http://www.uthweb.com/technology/arduino-and-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for programming questions. This question is off-topic since it is asking for a hardware recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of a right Arduino depends on the sort of peripherals you need for example if your barcode reader is SPI enabled and you can't bit-bang SPI then this counts for Hardware SPI usage and as such will take the SPI pins on the UNO which has support for only 1 SPI hardware connection but if you want more SPI connections go for a MEGA ,similarly UART, two wire etc are communication protocols that may be needed by you based on the chipssets you use in your project, also GPIO's are there which just turn on and off.
I will suggest starting off with an Arduino UNO which DIP ATmega328P and get a spare Bootloader acquipped ATmega328P chip standalone in case as a newbie you magic-smoke the chip on the board.